# Python. Find user folder to appdata

Tags: python

How can I find a path to appdata folder if C:\Users*username folder*\AppData  this folder isn't same as username?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That’s what the environment variables are for: `os.environ['APPDATA']`

Answer (score 2):

```
import os
print os.getenv('APPDATA')
```